# Optimize Normalmap rotation of a vector

Tags: glsl, libgdx, quaternions

I use a quaternion to rotate the normal vector of a mesh into the direction the normal map vector. I thought I could use the Quaternion. So I create a quaternion with the angle between the normal of the mesh and (0,0,1). Shortened the methods in libgdx, creation of the Quaternion looks like this

```
vec4 createQuaternion(vec3 normal) {
    float l_ang = acos(clamp(normal.z, -CONST_ONE, CONST_ONE))/CONST_TWO;
    float l_sin = sin(l_ang);
    return normalize(vec4(-normal.y * l_sin, normal.x * l_sin, CONST_ZERO, cos(l_ang)));
}
```

with this Quaternion I can rotate the normal of the mesh in the direction of the normal map. Therefore I use a method I've seen in the libgdx Quaternion (while v is the normal from the normalmap and m is the quaternion):

```
vec3 rotateNormal(vec3 v, vec4 m) {
    vec4 tmp1 = vec4(v,CONST_ZERO);
    vec4 tmp2 = vec4(m);
    // conjugate
    tmp2.x = -tmp2.x;
    tmp2.y = -tmp2.y;
    tmp2.z = -tmp2.z;
    tmp2 = mulLeft(tmp1, tmp2);
    tmp1 = mulLeft(m, tmp2);
    v.x = tmp1.x;
    v.y = tmp1.y;
    v.z = tmp1.z;
    return v;
}
```

The method mulLeft looks like that:

```
vec4 mulLeft(vec4 q, vec4 a) {
    float newX = q.w * a.x + q.x * a.w + q.y * a.z - q.z * a.y;
    float newY = q.w * a.y + q.y * a.w + q.z * a.x - q.x * a.z;
    float newZ = q.w * a.z + q.z * a.w + q.x * a.y - q.y * a.x;
    float newW = q.w * a.w - q.x * a.x - q.y * a.y - q.z * a.z;
    a.x = newX;
    a.y = newY;
    a.z = newZ;
    a.w = newW;
    return a;
}
```

For the use in the shader I just call:

```
normal = rotateNormal(normalMap, createQuaternion(normalMesh));
```

and **it works as expected**.

The only thing I am considered about is that I can imagine that there is a shorter way to write that. Especially the mulLeft Method. Is there?

What do you think about the whole method, turning the vector by quaternion instead of using NTB?
ntb looks a bit like too much calculation while animating the mesh.

Edit:
This is the a test with my sourcecode

[image: My Code]

This is a Test with Tenfour's suggestion

[image]

Edit2:

I shortened the whole thing to:

```
vec3 rotateNormal(vec3 normalMap, vec3 normal) {
    // create quaternion from cross(normal, vec3(0,0,1))
    float l_ang = acos(clamp(normal.z, -CONST_ONE, CONST_ONE))/CONST_TWO;
    float l_sin = sin(l_ang);
    vec4 quat = normalize(vec4(-normal.y * l_sin, normal.x * l_sin, CONST_ZERO, cos(l_ang)));

    // shortened function to double mulQuat the normalMap on the quaternion
    return vec3(
            quat.x*quat.x*normalMap.x - quat.y*quat.y*normalMap.x - quat.z*quat.z*normalMap.x + quat.w*quat.w*normalMap.x - CONST_TWO*quat.z*quat.w*normalMap.y + CONST_TWO*quat.y*quat.w*normalMap.z + CONST_TWO*quat.x *(quat.y*normalMap.y + quat.z*normalMap.z),
            -(quat.x*quat.x*normalMap.y) - quat.z*quat.z* normalMap.y + (quat.y*quat.y  + quat.w*quat.w ) * normalMap.y + CONST_TWO*quat.z *(quat.w*normalMap.x + quat.y*normalMap.z) + CONST_TWO*quat.x* (quat.y*normalMap.x - quat.w*normalMap.z),
            quat.y*(-CONST_TWO*quat.w*normalMap.x + CONST_TWO*quat.z*normalMap.y) + CONST_TWO*quat.x*(quat.z*normalMap.x + quat.w*normalMap.y) - quat.x*quat.x*normalMap.z - quat.y*quat.y*normalMap.z + (quat.z*quat.z  + quat.w*quat.w )* normalMap.z
    );
}
```

Input is the normal from the normal map and the normal of the mesh.
I am sure there's something better than that. what could that be?

Answer (score 0):

I found this

```
vec3 rotate_vector( vec4 quat, vec3 vec )
{
    return vec + 2.0 * cross( cross( vec, quat.xyz ) + quat.w * vec, quat.xyz );
}
```

[here](http://twistedpairdevelopment.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/rotating-a-vector-by-a-quaternion-in-glsl/). Does that work? Not sure how much less underlying math there is, but built-in GLSL functions can often take advantage of GPU optimizations.

Comment: It does not really work (see Edit in the original post), may be I should refactor the code and shorten it myself. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Rats. There probably is a way to shorten it into built-in functions like this, but 3D vector rotations with 2D matrices and cross products make my brain hurt.

Comment: You might try looking at the included shaders in the source code of cocos3d. Those are all written in ES GLSL. Might give you some ideas.